# Facebook Graph API, no usepic image

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, user-profile

Can't figure out how to detect if user actually has set his photo or not, because Graph API would return [this blank image](https://heatherchristenaschmidt.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/facebook_no_profile_pic2-jpg.gif) anyway.

is there is any way to find difference between real photo and this placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there is any way to find difference between real photo and this placeholder?

Read the profile picture details via API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/picture), include the parameter `redirect=false`, and the returned data structure will include a property `is_silhouette` that indicates whether the picture is just the default placeholder (`true`) or the user has their own profile picture set (`false`)

Comment: Thank You very much for your help. Will try it out!